# width of wrapper div and width of content right should increase depending on the content in content right

Tags: html, css

hi all I have html code like this

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {      
font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;     
font-size:12px; background-color: blue;
}

**#wrapper {        
width:900px;        
margin:0px auto;        
border:1px solid #bbb;      
padding:10px; background-color: pink;   
}**

#header 
{       
border:1px solid #bbb;      
height:80px;        
padding:10px;   
}   
#content 
{       
margin-top:10px;        
padding-bottom:10px;    
}   
#content div 
{       
padding:10px;       
border:1px solid #bbb;      
float:left; 
} 
**#images
{
position:relative; 
top:0px;
}** 
#content-left 
{       
width:380px;    
}       
**#content-right 
{ 
position:relative; 
top:0px;        
margin-left:10px;       
width:534px;    
}** 
#footer 
{       
float:left;     
margin-top:10px;        
margin-bottom:10px;     
padding:10px;       
border:1px solid #bbb;      
width:878px;    
}   
#bottom 
{       
clear:both;     
text-align:right;   
}



</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">  
<div id="header">Header</div>   
<div id="content">      
<div id="content-left"></div>       
**<div id="content-right"><div id="images"><img src="pics02.jpg"     
width="300px;height="900px" /></div>**
</div>  
</div>  
<div id="footer"></div> 
<div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a problem like if i insert some **content in content right and if the content is more than the width of content right first content right should expand then wrapper should expand** but this is not happening over there and is coming out of the wrapper. Can anyone guide me how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

you have fixed the width of the content-right. so it wont! it may adjust the height but it wont adjust width..you could use the min-width property to set the minimum width of the content-right...
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp

Comment: but if I use min-width and if the contents is more the content right will be positioned below of content-left. If we zoom in or zoom out the contents also will change.Thanks praveen for your reply

Comment: first of all! why would you like to add that kind of content in your div that overflows.?? in css we create a fixed structure and then put content in it. the content dimensions may change within the range of the parent container's dimension but not more than that.thats a bad css practice. if you like you can increase the width of the content-right div from the initial stage.

Comment: So there is no way to increase width dynamically according to the content.We need to adjust the width size of the content and need to display with in that corresponding content-right.  if there is any way we can adjust our content dynamically just update me. Thanks praveen.